# Associate an existing EIP to EC2 Instance in CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I have a CloudFormation to spin up my QA server and have a couple of Elastic IP's I have pre allocated. These are kept for my QA servers which are only launched when needed. What I have now is following which creates and allocates a new EIP to my instance.

```
Ec2Instance:
Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
Properties:
  UserData:
    Fn::Base64:
      Fn::Join:
      - ''
      - - IPAddress=
        - Ref: IPAddress
  ImageId:
    Fn::FindInMap:
    - RegionMap
    - Ref: AWS::Region
    - AMI
  IPAddress:
    Type: AWS::EC2::EIP
  IPAssoc:
    Type: AWS::EC2::EIPAssociation
    Properties:
      InstanceId:
        Ref: Ec2Instance
      EIP:
        Ref: IPAddress
```

Is there any option to list out existing EIP's and associate it with my instance?

Answer (score 0):

I see it has to be put in userdata.

```
 "setup2" : {
            "commands" : {
              "00_associate_eip" : {
                "command" : {
                  "Fn::Join" : [ "", [ "#!/bin/bash\n", "export AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=", {
                    "Ref" : "AWS::Region"
                  }, "\n", "aws ec2 associate-address", " --allow-reassociation", " --instance-id $(curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id)", " --allocation-id ", {
                    "Ref" : "ElasticVPN"
                  } ] ]
                }
              },
```